# Scrapy: How to use different settings.py for different project

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looking to use different settings for different project in scrapy, my directory structure is:

```
-projects
    -project1
        -spiders
        -settings.py
    -project2
        -spiders
        -settings.py
    -scrapy.cfg
```

My scrapy.cfg is:

```
[settings]
default = project1.settings

[deploy]
project = project1
```

The result shows that both project1 and project2 use project1.settings.

So, how do I use project1.settings for project1 and use project2.settings for project2?
Could I set it in scrapy.cfg?

Comment: I do have the exact same question. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Each scrapy project should contain it's own `scrapy.cfg` file.

So in your case you want to have `scrapy.cfg` under `project1` and `project2`

See [dccumentation on scrapy configuration settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#configuration-settings):

> Scrapy will look for configuration parameters in ini-style scrapy.cfg files in standard locations:
>
> 1. `/etc/scrapy.cfg` or `c:\scrapy\scrapy.cfg` (system-wide),
> 2. `~/.config/scrapy.cfg` (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`) and `~/.scrapy.cfg` ($HOME) for global (user-wide) settings, and
> 3. `scrapy.cfg` inside a scrapy project’s root (see next section).
>
> Settings from these files are merged in the listed order of preference: user-defined values have higher priority than system-wide defaults and project-wide settings will override all others, when defined.
>
> Scrapy also understands, and can be configured through, a number of environment variables. Currently these are:
>
> `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` (see Designating the settings)
>   `SCRAPY_PROJECT`
>   `SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL` (see Scrapy shell)

and [documentation on scrapy's default project structure](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#default-structure-of-scrapy-projects)

Comment: I try move scrapy.cfg to project1 and change it like this:
[settings]
default = settings

[deploy]
project = project1

then I have to change the settings:
SPIDER_MODULES = ['spiders']

after that i just coudn't import module from project1, like this:
form project1.items import ProjectItem
it will cause ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders.items'